# SimpleJdbcInsert Unable to locate columns for table 'user_models' so an insert statement can't be generated

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, transactions, spring-jdbc

I am getting this error

```
Unable to locate columns for table 'user_models' so an insert statement can't be generated
```

Using Spring 3.1.2. I am maintaining a legacy code. And it(the method throwing the exception) has the annotation `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)`. Also it is using caching and has the below annotation `@CacheEvict(value = "UserModel", key = "#userModel.id")` I am hitting dead ends on this exception. I found just one link regarding this error:
https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-4782
I couldnt make much sense out of it. can someone at least guide me in the right direction.

EDIT

Stack trace below:

```
Server Error occured while executing method [saveModel] org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unable to locate columns for table 'user_models' so an insert statement can't be generated
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.metadata.TableMetaDataContext.createInsertString(TableMetaDataContext.java:325)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcInsert.compileInternal(AbstractJdbcInsert.java:282)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcInsert.compile(AbstractJdbcInsert.java:265)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcInsert.checkCompiled(AbstractJdbcInsert.java:316)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcInsert.doExecute(AbstractJdbcInsert.java:342)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcInsert.execute(SimpleJdbcInsert.java:114)
        at com.capillary.recommender.model.user.data.dao.impl.UserModelDaoImpl.save(UserModelDaoImpl.java:344)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
        at com.capillary.common.spring.transaction.ProxyTransactionInterceptor.invoke(ProxyTransactionInterceptor.java:30)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor$1.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:58)
        at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:213)
        at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:66)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy67.save(Unknown Source)
        at com.capillary.recommender.model.user.UserModelStore.saveModel(UserModelStore.java:62)
        at com.capillary.recommender.model.user.UserModelStore.saveModel(UserModelStore.java:19)
        at com.capillary.recommender.thrift.ThriftRecommenderService.saveModel(ThriftRecommenderService.java:168)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
```

The snippet throwing the error below:

```
Map<String, Object> args = ImmutableMap.<String, Object>builder()
                .put(ID_COL, modelId)
                .put(ORG_ID_COL, orgId)
                .put(NAME_COL, name)
                .put(SCORES_TABLE_NAME_COL, scoresTableName)
                .put(TARGET_TABLE_NAME_COL, targetTableName)
                .put(ATTRIB_JSON_COL, attributes)
                .build();

        if (insert) {
            insert().withTableName(TABLE).execute(args);
            userModel.setId(modelId);
```

This above is the DaoImpl. The value of TABLE is declared in the layer above the Dao as

> public static final String TABLE = "user_models";

Comment: Can you please provide us with a stacktrace for this exception?

Comment: The exception means that SimpleJdbcInsert wasn't able to look up metadata for the table you are trying to insert into. You could provide the columns to use programmatically and not rely on the JDBC metadata. Could you post some code and the stacktrace?

Answer (score 3):

We had the same error.

Our 'tableName' was a synonym to a table in another schema.

But regarding https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-4782
Oracle Connection is configured with "includeSynonyms" = false by default.

Try this to fix that:

```
new SimpleJdbcInsert(datasource)
.includeSynonymsForTableColumnMetaData()
.withTableName("tableName");
```

Also we had pooledConnections so to handle this we had to specified native jdbc extractor:

```
new SimpleJdbcInsert(datasource)
.useNativeJdbcExtractorForNetaData(new OracleJdbc4NativeJdbcExtractor())
.includeSynonymsForTableColumnMetaData()
.withTableName("tableName");
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error once. The problem turned out to be the typo on the table name. Double check if you'd typed the table name correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Except the table name, You also need to specify the columns:

```
String[] columns = {"column1","column2"}

SimpleJdbcInsert jdbcInsert = new SimpleJdbcInsert(dataSource)
                .usingColumns(columns)
                .withTableName(table);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of using a postgresql database, you need to put your table name between quotes:

```
withTableName("\"my_table_name\"")
```

Answer (score -2):

u can try to change mysql connector/j's version that can't be 6.0.x and 5.1.45 is ok

Comment: Don't add comments here